# Error in Assigning an attribute to a resource in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am trying to allow a current user to invite another user and have that new invitee be assigned to a listing, but am getting an error when the invited user goes to sign up.

There are two models, User and Listing, that are related with a has_and_belongs_to_many on each model. There is also an Invitation model that contains a token and the listing that the invitee needs to be assigned to.

I am overriding the devise registrations controller:

```
  def new
    resource = build_resource({:invitation_token => params[:invitation_token]})
    resource.email = resource.invitation.recipient_email if resource.invitation
    respond_with resource
  end

  # POST /resource
  def create
    resource = build_resource
    resource.listings << resource.invitation.listing if resource.invitation
. . .
```

When I invite a new user and go to the signup (registrations/new) page, fill out the form, and click submit, it works fine.  But, if I miss a part of the form causing a validation error, when I then fill out the form correctly, and click submit, I get the following error:

```
Couldn't find Listing with id=0
```

The error appears to be occurring on the line:

```
resource.listings << resource.invitation.listing if resource.invitation
```

Without that line, the error doesn't happen.

Here is the error from the server logs:

```
  Listing Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "listings".* FROM "listings" WHERE "listings"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 0]]
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was actually in my view file where I had the following:

```
-if resource.listing_ids != []
  = f.hidden_field :listing_ids#, :value => resource.invitation.listing.id
```

It was left over from a previous attempt to pass the listing_ids in the params.